# Some images are being repeated in easy js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider

Hello I am using the easy js slider for image sliding. I want to show the 3 images per slide. here is my js code

```
 <?php
 $slide = true;
 $noOfItems = 3;
  //count($this->statSummary['top_products_data'] is having 5
 if (count($this->statSummary['top_products_data']) <= $noOfItems) {
   $slide = false;
 }
 ?>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        hoverStop:false,
        auto: false,
        hoverStop:false,
        continuous: false,
        controlsFade:true,
       <?php if ($slide) { ?>
            controlsShow: true,
       <?php } else { ?>
            controlsShow: false,
       <?php } ?>
        verticalHeight: 150
    });

});
```

Now what is happening, it shows three pics with next arrow, when I click on next button, one image slides and other image comes and it also shows previous button. But it shows first 2 images again (repeats those) then the next arrow disappears. I don't know why it is happending. Can any one tell me how to stop the repitition of first 2 images?

Here is my html

```
    <li class="rate sliderli">
     <div id="slider">
       <ul>
         <?php
            if (isset($this->statSummary['top_products_data']))
            {
              foreach ($this->statSummary['top_products_data'] as $top_product)
              {
                ?><li><img src="<?php echo $top_product['image_small']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $top_product['product_name']; ?>"/></li><?php
               }
              }
             ?>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
```

And my CSS looks like

```
 #slider{
 width: 474px;
 margin:10px auto;
}
#slider li{
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
#summaryBox ul li.sliderli{
position: relative;
width: 650px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us on jsfiddle, with normal images.. not the php code.

Comment: @Rafee how can I give the slider js files and jquery js files in jsfiddle? online url?

Comment: upload the files, on free sharing websites, take the url and add it to `resourses` in jsfiddle.net

Comment: You can work with http://jsfiddle.net/hh9FY/ if you want. Seems to work for me. (that's a minified version of easy slider 1.7).. I should have used smaller or shared pics, but you can change that if you want.